# Correct texture format for Moai with TexturePacker

Tags: textures, memory-efficiency

We are going to use [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com/) to create our texture atlases for a [Moai](http://getmoai.com/)-based game. I'm wondering what the correct texture format and image format is to use specifically for Moai. Should I just use png and RGBA4444 or can you use pvr and PVRTC4? PVRTC4 format seems to create a texture that indicates less RAM usage but I'm unsure if we can use this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post: http://getmoai.com/forums/post667.html#p667 MOAI supports PVR format.

But in the end it's a matter of quality. PVRTC may be good enough for background images but I would not recommend using it for foreground because the quality is not too good through the heavy lossy compression.

Comment: Looks like PVR is only iOS so that's a no go then. Thanks.